# How to Access `UItextView` data from another view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

How I access the body of `UITextView` from another view controller for email here is my code

> EmergencyMessageController *ViewB1 = [[EmergencyMessageController
>   alloc]initWithNibName:@"EmergencyMessageController" bundle:nil];
>
> NSString  *Em1 = ViewB1.Emsg.text;

```
 NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" ",Em1];//my problem is here to access Em1 data

    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"Emergency Message"];
    [controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES]; 
    [controller setToRecipients:recipients];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Comment: Is the all code in the same method? 
When you instantiate ViewB1, i assume you are trying to get a controller that is already showed somewhere. Is that right?

Comment: Yes right.I want to access email body that i have already enter in another view controller in UITextView form.

Comment: Ok and in your hierarchy, this "another view controller" is just before the one with the code? I ask because here you are instantiating other "EmergencyMessageController" thats why you cant access the info. But if the controller with the email body is parent of this, there are some easy solutions.

Comment: Yes you are right sir but the controller with the email body is not the parent of this.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating another instance of "EmergencyMessageController" viewcontroller here, it won't give you any values.
You have to use the same instance variable using which you have set the email body in EmergencyMessageController.
or else as Vertogo said, this EmergencyMessageController should be the parent of this second view controller, so that you can easily access parent view controllers properties.

Comment: Ok Sir Thanks So Now Can you tell me or give any link that how to make a parent and child view controller and access textView values from child to parent say(that if my child is setting View and I give values to textView from child and show in my parent View Controller)?

Comment: AnyOne There plz help me I'am Stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

*Hey user2396021 this is a simple example of Parent-Child View Controller,hope this will help you.*

**ParentViewController.h**

Declare your textView as a class variable in parent view controller as below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *mytextView;
@end
```

**ParentViewController.m**

Add textview to parentView Controller as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _mytextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 30)];
    [_mytextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_mytextView]; 
}
```

**ChildViewController.h**

Make ParentViewController as a superclass(or you can say parentclass) of ChildViewController as below

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"
@interface ChildViewController : ParentViewController
@end
```

**ChildViewController.m**

Now you can easily access any class variable of parent class(ParentViewController) using "super" keyword.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSLog(@"Text value of uitextview from Parent class %@",[[super mytextView]text]);
}
```